# Pass Edit Text Content To RecyclerView in Next Activity

Tags: android, android-layout, android-recyclerview

I am passing the `EditText` values from one activity to another Activity that contains `RecyclerView`. But i got a problem which remains Unsolvable for me.

My `main.xml` contains `Edit text` field and add `Button`. On click of add `Button` the `Edit Text` value should pass to `RecyclerView` in next XML.

This is my Main Activity:

```
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity;
import android.support.v7.widget.LinearLayoutManager;
import android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.Toast;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity;
import android.support.v7.widget.LinearLayoutManager;
import android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.Toast;

 public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity {

private RecyclerView myRecyclerView;
private LinearLayoutManager linearLayoutManager;
private RecyclerViewAdapter myRecyclerViewAdapter;

EditText nameField;
Button btnAdd;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    myRecyclerView = (RecyclerView) findViewById(R.id.myrecyclerview);

    nameField = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.namefield);
    btnAdd = (Button) findViewById(R.id.addbutton);
    btnAdd.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            /*String newName = nameField.getText().toString();*/
            Intent i = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), ListFromMain.class);
            startActivity(i);
            /*myRecyclerViewAdapter.add(0,newName);
            Toast.makeText(MainActivity
                    .this,"You added" +newName.toUpperCase()+ "in your view",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();*/

        }
    });
}
```

}

My Recycler Adapter

```
public class RecyclerViewAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<RecyclerViewAdapter.ItemHolder> {

private List<String> itemsName;
private OnItemClickListener onItemClickListener;
private LayoutInflater layoutInflater;

public RecyclerViewAdapter(Context context){
    layoutInflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);
    itemsName = new ArrayList<String>();
}

@Override
public RecyclerViewAdapter.ItemHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
    View itemView = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.text_view,parent, false);
    return new ItemHolder(itemView, this);
}

@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(RecyclerViewAdapter.ItemHolder holder, int position) {
    holder.setItemName(itemsName.get(position));

}

@Override
public int getItemCount() {
    return itemsName.size();
}

public void setOnItemClickListener(OnItemClickListener listener){
    onItemClickListener = listener;
}

public OnItemClickListener getOnItemClickListener(){
    return onItemClickListener;
}

public interface OnItemClickListener{
    public void onItemClick(ItemHolder item, int position);
}

public void add(int location, String iName){
    itemsName.add(location, iName);
    notifyItemInserted(location);
}


public static class ItemHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder implements View.OnClickListener{

    private RecyclerViewAdapter parent;
    TextView textItemName;

    public ItemHolder(View itemView, RecyclerViewAdapter parent) {
        super(itemView);
        itemView.setOnClickListener(this);
        this.parent = parent;
        textItemName = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.textview);
    }

    public void setItemName(CharSequence name){
        textItemName.setText(name);
    }

    public CharSequence getItemName(){
        return textItemName.getText();
    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        final OnItemClickListener listener = parent.getOnItemClickListener();
        if(listener != null){
            listener.onItemClick(this, getPosition());
        }
    }
}}
```

ListActivity

```
public class ListFromMain extends ActionBarActivity implements RecyclerViewAdapter.OnItemClickListener{

private RecyclerView myRecyclerView;
private LinearLayoutManager linearLayoutManager;
private RecyclerViewAdapter myRecyclerViewAdapter;
@Override
protected void onCreate( Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.reycler_list);

    RecyclerView recyclerView = (RecyclerView) findViewById(R.id.myrecyclerview);

    linearLayoutManager =
            new LinearLayoutManager(this, LinearLayoutManager.VERTICAL, false);

    myRecyclerViewAdapter = new RecyclerViewAdapter(this);

    myRecyclerView.setAdapter(myRecyclerViewAdapter);
    myRecyclerView.setLayoutManager(linearLayoutManager);


}
@Override
public void onItemClick(RecyclerViewAdapter.ItemHolder item, int position) {
    Toast.makeText(this,
            "Remove " + position + " : " + item.getItemName(),
            Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
}}
```

Main.xml

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
tools:context=".MainActivity"
android:orientation="vertical">


<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical">
    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/namefield"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
    <Button
        android:id="@+id/addbutton"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Add"/>
</LinearLayout>
```

Recycler_list.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">

<android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
    android:id="@+id/myrecyclerview"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"/>
 </LinearLayout>
```

textview xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
 <TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/textview"/>
```

The edit text value from main should be displayed in recycler_list.

Comment: can you put what you want to do like sreenshot !!

Comment: Its just like when i write animal in my edit text field the animal should be displayed in recyclerlist in next activity

Comment: So where's the other Activity? You only posted the code for MainActivity.

Comment: Pass the value in the `Intent` to the `Activity` with the `RecyclerView`.

Comment: where is your activity_main layout ? As per your Main Activity your activity_main  should contain recyclerview.

Comment: you have given edittext and recyclerview in same Activity, where is other Activity code,

Comment: in another activity there i just call the xml that contains recycler view

Comment: If ListForMain.class have a recyclerview then that recyclerview's adapter should add editext text in that.

Comment: so what should i do for that

Comment: use constructor and pass value in that

Comment: First you should move all your code of recyclerview from Main Activity to ListActivity

Comment: yes i moved it and

Comment: then always update your list in second Activity and then refresh your recyclerview when condition for intent received is true.

Answer (score 1):

create a arraylist inside your **ListFromMain** like:

```
private ArrayList<String> itemsList;
```

and inside your **onCreate**

```
itemsList = new ArrayList<>();
.
.
myRecyclerViewAdapter = new RecyclerViewAdapter(this, itemsName);
```

and inside your adapter

```
public RecyclerViewAdapter(Context context, ArrayList<String> itemsList){
layoutInflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);
this.itemsName = itemsList;
}
```

Now, when you click on **btnAdd** inside your **MainActivity** e.g

```
btnAdd.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {

        String newName = nameField.getText().toString();
        Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, ListFromMain.class);
        intent.putExtra("item_name", newName);
        startActivity(intent);

    }
});
```

and inside **onCreate** of **ListFromMain** activity class

```
if(getIntent().hasExtra("item_name")) {
itemsList.add(getIntent().getStringExtra("item_name"));
myRecyclerViewAdapter.notifyDataSetChange();
}
```

Hope it will help you out.

Comment: I have changed my answer.

Comment: it does not pass the new name to Recycler list view into next activity

Comment: when you are opening your next activity?

Comment: Its just like when i write animal in my edit text field the animal should be displayed in recyclerlist in next activity after clicking add button

Comment: but in above code **recyclerlist** is in your first activity not in next activity. Please go through your code.

Comment: I have changed my answer too

Comment: items list is from adapter?

Comment: the below shalini code seems to be allright to me but i want this edit text view to recycler View

Comment: yeah you can follow that approach too.

Comment: But it is not listing in recycler view

Comment: **edittext** is in your first activity, and **recycleview** is in your next activity, they how you can show this edittext in recycleview?

Answer (score 1):

I have removed recyclerview code from here,on click of button you are passing a list of name in the next Activity.

```
public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity implements      
RecyclerViewAdapter.OnItemClickListener{

 EditText nameField;
 Button btnAdd;
 List<String> nameList;

 @Override
 protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
   super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
   setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
   nameList = new Arraylist<>();

nameField = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.namefield);
btnAdd = (Button)findViewById(R.id.addbutton);
btnAdd.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        String newName = nameField.getText().toString();
        nameList.add(newName);
        Intent i = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),ListFromMain.class);
         intent.putStringArrayListExtra("key",nameList);
         startActivity(intent);
        Toast.makeText(MainActivity
                .this,"You added" +newName.toUpperCase()+ "in your view",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

    }
});
 }

@Override
 public void onItemClick(RecyclerViewAdapter.ItemHolder item, int position) {
   Toast.makeText(this,
        "Remove " + position + " : " + item.getItemName(),
        Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
}}
```

Here we are setting recyclerview and getting intent from the prvious Activity and setting that list in constructor of Adapter.
ListActivity

```
     public class ListFromMain extends ActionBarActivity{
        private RecyclerView myRecyclerView;
        private LinearLayoutManager linearLayoutManager;
        private RecyclerViewAdapter myRecyclerViewAdapter;
     @Override
      protected void onCreate( Bundle savedInstanceState) {
         super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
         setContentView(R.layout.reycler_list);
        ArrayList<String> nameList = getIntent().getStringArrayListExtra("key");
          myRecyclerView = (RecyclerView)findViewById(R.id.myrecyclerview);

         linearLayoutManager =
        new LinearLayoutManager(this, LinearLayoutManager.VERTICAL,     false);


          myRecyclerViewAdapter = new RecyclerViewAdapter(this,nameList);
          myRecyclerView.setAdapter(myRecyclerViewAdapter);
          myRecyclerView.setLayoutManager(linearLayoutManager);



   }
}
```

there is not much change in the adapter just one is there that you initialize your list here from constructor that's it.
RecyclerAdaptger

```
    public class RecyclerViewAdapter extends     RecyclerView.Adapter<RecyclerViewAdapter.ItemHolder> {

  private List<String> itemsName;
  private OnItemClickListener onItemClickListener;
  private LayoutInflater layoutInflater;

 public RecyclerViewAdapter(Context context,ArrayList<String> nameList){
     layoutInflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);
     itemsName = nameList;
  }

   @Override
    public RecyclerViewAdapter.ItemHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
     View itemView = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.text_view,parent, false);
     return new ItemHolder(itemView, this);
  }

   @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(RecyclerViewAdapter.ItemHolder holder, int position) {
       holder.setItemName(itemsName.get(position));

   }

   @Override
   public int getItemCount() {
       return itemsName.size();
   }

    public void setOnItemClickListener(OnItemClickListener listener){
         onItemClickListener = listener;
    }

     public OnItemClickListener getOnItemClickListener(){
          return onItemClickListener;
      }

     public interface OnItemClickListener{
           public void onItemClick(ItemHolder item, int position);
    }

    public static class ItemHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder implements View.OnClickListener{

private RecyclerViewAdapter parent;
TextView textItemName;

public ItemHolder(View itemView, RecyclerViewAdapter parent) {
    super(itemView);
    itemView.setOnClickListener(this);
    this.parent = parent;
    textItemName = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.textview);
}

public void setItemName(CharSequence name){
    textItemName.setText(name);
}

public CharSequence getItemName(){
    return textItemName.getText();
}

@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
    final OnItemClickListener listener = parent.getOnItemClickListener();
    if(listener != null){
        listener.onItemClick(this, getPosition());
    }
}
  }}
```

Comment: It will always be great and easy to understand if you mention where and what changes you made as what is in OP so will be easy to understand.

Comment: But i need the list in RecyclerView into next xml.

Comment: yes it will happen this list only contains string of names, when you set this in recycler Adapter it will show this data in your list item

Comment: i have set the recycler Adapter in ListFrommain class

Comment: No i am not being able to set the namelist to the recycler view adapter